# Ensure underscore functions and variables are private

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Is it possible to set a rule whereby functions/variables in a class that have a leading underscore should be marked private?

For example

```
_myFunc () {}         // fail
private _myFunc () {} // pass
```

Similarly

```
_myVar: string = ''         // fail
private _myVar: string = '' // pass
```

There is an [example in the docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/#enforce-that-private-members-are-prefixed-with-an-underscore) that specifies any private member has to start with an underscore, but there is nothing mentioned about the inverse - underscore member has to be private.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this with the following config, using the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule:

- firstly, **forbid** the leading underscore for **all** class members.
- secondly, **require** a leading underscore only for **private** class members.

```js
rules: {
  // ...
  "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
     "error",
     {
       "selector": "memberLike",
       "format": ["camelCase"],
       "leadingUnderscore": "forbid"
     },
     {
       "selector": "memberLike",
       "modifiers": ["private"],
       "format": ["camelCase"],
       "leadingUnderscore": "require"
     }
   ]
}
```

**Example**:

```js
_fooFunc () {}          // fail
private barFunc () {}   // fail  
private _bazFunc () {}  // pass


_fooVar = '';           // fail
private barVar = '';    // fail
private _bazVar = '';   // pass
```

**Eslint output**:

```
error  Class Method name `_fooFunc` must not have a leading underscore     @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
error  Class Method name `barFunc` must have one leading underscore(s)     @typescript-eslint/naming-convention

error  Class Property name `_fooVar` must not have a leading underscore    @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
error  Class Property name `barVar` must have one leading underscore(s)    @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
```